# How to use same filegroup definition in different subprojects

Tags: bazel

I need to declare specific resources for some of sub-projects and I'm doing it following way

```
filegroup(
    name = "some_resources",
    visibility = ["//:app"],
    srcs = glob([
        "src/my/resources/**/*.resources",
    ]),
)
```

In any subproject however the path where one can find resources is the same. My question would be - what is the most bazelian (bazelish?) way to minimize code duplication in this particular case?

Basically I want to have something like
expose_some_resources() in relevant subprojects.

and then make this resources visible for every app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the filegroup into a macro in a `.bzl` file, and load and run that macro in the relevant subprojects.

so something like:

`workspace/resources.bzl`:

```
def expose_some_resources():
  native.filegroup(
    name = "some_resources",
    visibility = ["//:app"],
    srcs = native.glob([
        "src/my/resources/**/*.resources",
    ]),
  )
```

`workspace/subproject/BUILD`:

```
load("//:resources.bzl", "expose_some_resources")
expose_some_resources()
```

You might also consider adding some error checking to the macro, like checking that the macro is called only once per package using [native.existing_rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/native.html#existing_rule), or checking that the glob returns 1 or more files.

Comment: are you 100% sure? The thing is that putting it into function is the first thing I've tried before asking the question - I'm getting 'name 'filegroup' is not defined'
with this definition - even if I'm not using it anywhere (bazel version: Build label: 0.14.0-homebrew)

Comment: I've reexamined everything and quite positive this does not work - I've also checked with 0.15.0-homebrew

Comment: In macros it should be `native.filegroup`, plain `filegroup` only works in build files. I've edited my answer to include the native part, sorry for the confusion.